# How to extract all file names out of a folder in c# and display them in a text file or csv

Tags: c#, file, console-application

I have loads of images in a folder called X:\myfolder\photos

How to extract all the names of the files in the above folder location and put it in a txt file or csv file. Can I do this in c# in a console application? or even just use cmd without creating an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below code for your query. You can use this code in console application and use it.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetFileNamesandWriteInTxt();
    }

    public static void GetFileNamesandWriteInTxt()
    {
        string path = @'X:\myfolder\photos';
        DirectoryInfo dr = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] mFile = dr.GetFiles();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\FileNames.txt", true);
        foreach (FileInfo fiTemp in mFile)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(fiTemp.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(fiTemp.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
```

Hope this will work for you!

Thanks,
Anshul

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or `GetFiles` and [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var allPaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"X:\myfolder\photos");
File.WriteAllLines(pathToCsvFile, allPaths);
```

If you only want the name of the files and not the complete paths use `Path.GetFileName`:

```
File.WriteAllLines(pathToCsvFile, allPaths.Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p)));
```